# Meaning of closed under an associative product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, associativity

I know the meaning of associative binary operation. I know the meaning of closed under a binary operation. Does closed under an associative product means:

$$ a*(b*c) \in G \implies (a*b)*c \in G$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(closd under associative product *) = (closed under product *) + (product * is associative).

Answer (score 3):

No. It means closed under a product, which happens to be associative.

Comment: I am mentioning the question from Herstien.
Let G be a nonempty set closed under an associative product, which
in addition satisfies:
(a) There exists an $e \in G$ such that $a· e = a \forall a \in G$.
(b) Give $a \in G$, there exists an element $a \in G$ such that $a·y(a) = e$.
Prove that G must be a group under this product.


So i hope the question itself is the definition of a Group?